# Javascript function to ensure string has space every n characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I know in javascript you can add a character every n characters in a string using regex:

```
str.replace(/(.{5})/g,"$1*");
```

This inserts a '*' every 5 characters in a string.

However, I want a way of only adding a character where it doesn't exist already.

eg. Insert a space where needed to ensure there is a space character at least every 5 characters (and don't insert where not needed):

```
myfunc('01234567890', ' ', 5) = '01234 56789 0'
myfunc('01 234567890', ' ', 5) = '01 23456 7890'
myfunc('01 234 56789 0', ' ', 5) = '01 234 56789 0'
```

Is this possible using regex or some other way in javascript?

Comment: I added description to the solution in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45861793/3832970). Please check the answers below and consider accepting the one that works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `.` with `[0-9]` to match digits only and use a negative lookahead `(?!...)` where `...` is your char:

```js
function myfunc(s, ch, limit) {
  var rx = new RegExp(
    "[0-9]{"+limit+"}"+ // Match a digit, limit times
    "(?!"+  // Only match if, immediately to the right, there is no
    ch.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')+ // delimiting char (escaped)
    "|$)", // or end of string
    "g"); // Global modifier, replace all occurrences
  return s.replace(rx, "$&" + ch); // Replace with the match itself + delimiting char
}
console.log(myfunc('01234567890', ' ', 5))    // = '01234 56789 0'
console.log(myfunc('01 234567890', ' ', 5))   // = '01 23456 7890'
console.log(myfunc('01 234 56789 0', ' ', 5)) // = '01 234 56789 0'
```

The sample regex generated will look like `[0-9]{5}(?! |$)` here. The `[0-9]{5}(?! |$)` will match 5 digits that are not followed with a space or end of string (added because you rarely want to insert anything at the end of the string, so, if you want to also insert spaces at the end of the string, remove `|$` from the pattern), and the replacement  `$&`  will replace it with itself (`$&`) and a space after.

Note that the `ch` is escaped with `.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')` just in case it is a special regex metacharacter (like  `(` or `)`).

Answer (score 5):

Use `\d` to match digits, so match 5 digits in a row with `\d{5}`, and insert a space after using `$1`; Also use a look ahead *(?=\S)* to assert there is no white space after already:

```js
var samples = ['01234567890', '01 234567890', '01 234 56789 0', '0123456789'];

console.log(
  samples.map(s => s.replace(/(\d{5})(?=\S)/g, '$1 '))
);
```

Comment: Just a note: The last example has a double space..  I assume another regex on this to remove double space would be the best option?.

Comment: No. problem..  Nice fix too..  Hopefully the down voter will retract.  As this regex looks the easiest to follow..

Comment: @Keith Thanks for the comment.

Comment: While this is OK for a hard-coded scenario (with space as a delimiting char), I think it won't eventually help OP since the character to be inserted may be not a space, it is a variable char. Then, `(?=\S)` won't work.

Comment: Yes - would it be possible to have this as a function that takes as input the number of characters and the replace character?