# Include a space between words longer than n characters

Tags: r, regex, string

I have a character vector.

```
x <- c('This is a simple text', 'this is a veryyyyyyyyyy long word', 'Replacethis andalsothis')
```

I want to insert a space between a word which is longer than `n` characters. For this example, we can consider `n = 10`. I would prefer a `regex` solution but if you think there are other alternatives I wouldn't mind to try that.

The output that I am looking for -

```
c('This is a simple text', 'this is a veryyyyyyy yyy long word', 'Replacethi s andalsothi s')
```

I have tried using [the solution from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45861682/16024709) by making the necessary changes for my data but it doesn't give the required output.

```
sub('(.{10})(?=\\S)//g', '\\1 ', x, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "This is a simple text"           "this is a veryyyyyyyy long word" "Replacethis andalsothis"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```r
gsub("\\b(\\w{10})\\B", "\\1 ", x) # If your words only consist of letters/digits/_
gsub("(?<!\\S)(\\S{10})(?=\\S)", "\\1 ", x, perl=TRUE) # If the "words" are non-whitespace char chunks
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vSYgYr/1) and [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vSYgYr/2), and [the R demo](https://ideone.com/Ee5o2S):

```r
x <- c('This is a simple text', 'this is a veryyyyyyyyyy long word', 'Replacethis andalsothis')
gsub("\\b(\\w{10})\\B", "\\1 ", x)
# => [1] "This is a simple text" "this is a veryyyyyyy yyy long word" "Replacethi s andalsothi s"

x <- c("this is a veryyyyyyy|yyy long word")
gsub("(?<!\\S)(\\S{10})(?=\\S)", "\\1 ", x, perl=TRUE)
# => [1] "this is a veryyyyyyy |yyy long word"
```

The regex matches...

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(\w{10})` - ten word chars
- `\B` - only when there is another word char appears immediately on the right (so, the tenth word char is not the end char of the word).

And

- `(?<!\S)` - a location at the start of string or right after a whitespace
- `(\S{10})` - Group 1: ten non-whitespace chars
- `(?=\S)` - immediately to the right, there must be a non-whitespace char.

Comment: Thank you @Wiktor for your quick answer. I just noticed in my actual data some text include special symbols like `'this is a veryyyyyyy|yyy long word'`. In this case, I would expect output as `'this is a veryyyyyyy |yyy long word'`. Do you think regex can be updated to handle that ? I tried replacing `\\w` with `.` to match any character but apparently it didn't help. `gsub("\\b(.{10})\\B", "\\1 ", x)`

Comment: @user16024709 Yes, it is `gsub("(?<!\\S)(\\S{10})(?=\\S)", "\\1 ", x, perl=TRUE)`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vSYgYr/2).